Continuity and Neighborhoods: Validity and Counterexample for the Converse Statement
Let $f$ be a function defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $V$, denoted $f|_V$, is continuous on $V$. Specifically, the map
$$[
f : V \to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto f(x),
]$$
is continuous.Is this correct, and is there a counterexample to the converse?
